# Deploying rails app to heroku which uses raw sql code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Rails has a emphasis on using Active record which abstract's queries sent to the database. Thus Heroku can use postgresql without us having to rewrite queries.

What if rails app uses raw sql and we now want to deploy the app to heroku, how do we do that.

The model contains code like this

```
sql = "Select * from ... your sql query here"
records_array = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
```

Comment: what's wrong with that lines ? Its supposed to work actually, if you have migrated a table.

Comment: If you are using a database other than postgres in development then you may need to modify your raw sql to conform.

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Active Record Migrations mechanism which allows you to use raw SQL queries as described in sections 3.7, 3.9.

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#when-helpers-aren-t-enough

Comment: This makes a tonne of sense. Thanks a tonne :)